# How to hide the navigation bar and fullscreen when using adjustresize?

Tags: android, navigation

I use this code to hide navigation bar.

```
public void hideNavigation() {
    try {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            );

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {
            registerSystemUiVisibility();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void registerSystemUiVisibility() {
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                hideNavigation();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But when I show Dialog or focus edittext up keyboard shown, navigation bar will come up again. Code doesn't work. Can you hepl me? I using adjustresize because fixed header no scroll when keyboard show. thanks
When keyboard show:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBmv5.jpg)

when keyboard hide:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csje0.jpg)

Comment: Does the navigation bar closes when keyboard is gone?

Comment: yes naumang-burman, navigation bar closes when keyboard is gone. but have space in bottom? view image

Comment: Hmm, Okay try my below answer